# C# Showing XML data

Tags: c#, xml

Is there any component which can load XML fast?
I have already use textbox and webbrowser to show XML they work perfectly, but due to the large amount of data stored in my XML (200MB) it takes me 30 seconds to display it. Is there any other component which could show XML data faster?

Comment: Showing your existing code is a good place to start.

Comment: For a browser to load and render a data structure of 200MB in 30 secs is very reasonable.  What other client platform is available to you?  If you require a browser, the only thing that may 'speed it up' from the user experience is to break it up and send it to the client dynamically as needed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comment by @PinnyM - 30 seconds does not sound unreasonable for such a large document depending on the client machine. Depending on the browser - it will be rendering this file with any combination of CSS, JavaScript or other add-on. These technologies are not really designed for such large files.

You may consider changing the mime-type and opening the file with a tool like notepad which will not render the XML  in a pretty-print format, but should be much faster to display the XML mark up.

Comment: And for your complete answer what is the right format for changing the mimetype to open with notepad?